# Can I make fck editor draggable?

Tags: asp.net, fckeditor

I want make FCK editor draggable in my asp.net application.
drag FCK editor with mouse pointer movement.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [jQuery Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).